# Differences between Sitecore 8 Social Network and Sitecore 7's 3rd party, Social Connect Module

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am in the process of researching a upgrade between a Sitecore 7.1 website to Sitecore 8.2. The site has the **Social Connect Module** installed.

I notice in Sitecore 8's Content Explorer, there is a pre-installed Social network structure. That looks very similar to the structure used in Sitecore 7.1's Social Connect Module.

My question is

1. Is this the same Sitecore 7 Social Connect Module just included in
   Sitecore 8 installs?
2. If so, are there any notable changes I should consider between the
       c# api?

I'm hoping that pre-existing user controls will just work. That would be awesome.

If you have any links to documents would be nice. Can't seems to find the right search term combo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is the same module included into Sitecore Exprience Platform starting from [8.0 initial release](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%208%200/Release%20Notes) (see the "Social Connected" section). Unfortunately there is no breaking changes report published, probably because the entire module became a *new* Platform component.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was struggling to find that confirmation. 
that makes my life a lot easier (thumbs up)